# WHEN to use serialize vs just regular POST

Tags: php, jquery

I recently asked a question that was partially answered but I was hoping someone could explain this a little clearer. Its regarding PHP and the serialize function.

So I have a form with 12 fields, all with names. Traditionally I would just use the POST method, send them to a PHP page and then supply them into a database.

Today I stumbled upon the serialize method but after using it, it seems like it doesnt do anything that a regular POST statement would do. For example, if I wanted to use serialize, I would do the following:

```
var formData = $('#contForm').serialize();
$.post('functs.php',formData,dispAdd);
```

Then to print a value I would use

```
echo $_POST['value_name']
```

What I see happening is that with or without the serialize, I get the same results. Am I missing something here?

Comment: serialize is shortest way to collect all form data and send it...

Comment: Not really though because it works without even using serialize?

Comment: Yes, if you not use ajax, the data will be posted, but if you use ajax, and not use serialize, you have to create your key-value pairs manually

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you because I hadnt gotten to my callback function yet. I was just trying to figure this out first but that wouldve drove me nuts later. So when using AJAX to talk to the server serialize is needed. GOTCHA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded
>   notation. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form
>   elements. The form elements can be of several types. [Read more](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

`.serialize()` is used when you are sending data through an AJAX request. It's the same as submitting a form using a submit button. Only difference it when you use AJAX it does not refresh the page. That's why you get the same results even though you submit the form using a submit button or `.serialize()` when using AJAX.

[.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) would be an alternative to `.serialize()`.

**Remember** if you don't use `.serialize()` you have to create your key-value pairs manually as @Akam mentioned in the comment above.

And finally

When to use serialize <-- When you use AJAX to post data

When regular POST <-- When you use submit button to post data

Comment: Great thank you! I also found a nice little tutorial here too http://www.namepros.com/webmaster-tutorials/281176-php-using-serialize-handle-store-arrays.html

Comment: This post was EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you for such great explanations. I always learn a ton on these boards.